# jQuery Animate Not Working (Position has been set)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

this has been driving me nuts. Putting a slider together and the image will slideDown, but when I change to animate, it stops working.

Position has been set to relative. Any ideas?

```
 function carousel() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("pf-grid-items");
    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("rotateText");
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("img1");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
      t[j].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var d = 0; d < image.length; d++) {
      image[d].style.display = "none";
    }

    slideIndex++;

    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    var output = x[slideIndex-1]
    var imageSlide = image[slideIndex-1]
    if (slideIndex % 2 !==0){

    $(output).slideDown(1000).promise().done(function(){

      textCarousel(t)
      $(imageSlide).animate({left:"250px"});
        $(output).fadeOut(5000);
    })
  } else {
    $(output).fadeIn(1000).promise().done(function(){

      textCarousel(t)
        $(output).fadeOut(5000);
    })
  }
  setTimeout(carousel, 7000);
}
```

### CSS:

```
.img1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('./flex/angular.png');
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: You should create a (non)working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), because we see no HTML, not all Javascript you use above (as `textCarousel(t)` function). I tried to create [one](https://jsfiddle.net/bwb2r73r/), but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$.animate()` and altering the `left` property, you can do that in CSS by assigning a class that applies `translateX()` (to move the element horizontally, doesn't require any unique `position`ing) and using `transition` to animate it. `transition`ing `transform` properties is much more performant than using jquery to animate the `left` property.

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  $('div').addClass('move');
})
```

```css
div {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.move {
  transform: translateX(250px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>div</div>
<button>click</button>
```